# Wanted to know real use of property() in python

Tags: python

I am new and trying property() in python. I saw an example and tried to execute that but I am receiving an error. I tried the code below:

```
class proper(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.x = 4   
      def setx(self,val):
          self.x = val
      def getx(self):
          return self.x
      def delx(self):
          del self.x

      p = property(setx,getx,delx,'i am doc')

pr = proper()
pr.setx(7)
print pr.getx()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test3.py", line 148, in <module>
    pr.p=5
TypeError: getx() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what line 148 is - but it doesn't refer to the code you posted.

The whole point of using property is that you can define methods which make a data item look like an attribute.

With your class definition as posted you can now do :

```
pr = proper()
pr.x = 7 # No need to call pr.setx
print pr.x # no need to call pr.sety
```

This is a very basic and redundant use of properties.

But say you define setx as :

```
def setx( self, val):
    if val < 0:
        raise ValueError("'x' cannot be negative")
     self.x = val
```

You now have a special attribute x which can never be negative. Note I have not been able to test this, as I don't have access to a Python implementation.

Comment: ok, if we do call x with object then it is simple and no use of property(). Actually i wanted to know the use of property()

Comment: The use of property is that you can define your setx, getx methods to do special things - for instance: limit the values that the attribute can be set to, calculate a value for your attribute on the fly rather than storing it. In your simple example though there is no benefit to using property.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of a useful setx definition

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you have created your `p` property with its arguments in the wrong order.

Try:

```
p = property(getx, setx, delx, 'i am doc') # getter before setter!
```

The error was happening because `getx` was being called when `setx` should have been. Because they take different numbers of arguments, this was breaking things.

Note that a more elegant way of setting up a property is to use decorators as you define the accessor methods:

```
@property
def p(self):         # formerly getx
    'i am doc'
    return self.x

@p.setter
def p(self, value):  # formerly setx
    self.x = value

@p.deleter
def p(self):         # formerly delx
    del self.x
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how properties are meant to be accessed.

Adapted from the [Python documentation for `property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):
If then `pr` is an instance of `proper`, `pr.x` will invoke `getx`, `pr.x = setx` will invoke the setter and `del pr.x` the deleter, `delx`.

Therefore, you aren't supposed to call it as `pr.setx(7)`.